# Create a dictonary from weighted edges

Tags: python

I try to get a dictonary that connects links with there dedicated weights. These weights are in my example all set to 200.

That is just for your understanding how the underlying graph is build up:

```
Gates = 2
Depots = 1 
Zwischenknoten = 5 
Parkpositionen = 2 

#Graph Nodes
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
for i in range(1, Gates+1, 1):
    G.add_node('g' + str(i), pos=(i, 30), color='turquoise', type='gates')
for j in range(1, Depots+1, 1):
    G.add_node('bd' + str(j), pos=(j+Gates, 30), color='green', type='depots')
for m in range(1, Zwischenknoten+1, 1):
    G.add_node('ni' + str(m), pos=(m, 20), color='blue')
for n in range(1, Parkpositionen+1, 1):
    G.add_node('p' + str(n), pos=(n+Gates+Depots, 10), color='red', type='parking')

#Graph Connections
for i in range(1, Gates+1, 1):
    G.add_edge('ni' + str(i), 'g' + str(i))
    G.add_edge('g' + str(i), 'ni' + str(i))
for j in range(1, Depots+1, 1):
    G.add_edge('ni' + str(j + Gates), 'bd' + str(j))
    G.add_edge('bd' + str(j), 'ni' + str(j + Gates))
for z in range(1, Parkpositionen+1, 1):
    G.add_edge('ni' + str(z + Gates + Depots), 'p' + str(z))
    G.add_edge('p' + str(z), 'ni' + str(z + Gates + Depots))
for r in range(1, Zwischenknoten, 1):
    G.add_edge('ni' + str(r), 'ni' + str(r+1))
    G.add_edge('ni' + str(r+1), 'ni' + str(r))
```

Here I build links with an underscore as they should be defined:

```
#Links
nodelist = G.edges()

def join_tuple_string(strings_tuple) -> str:
    return '_'.join(strings_tuple)

result = map(join_tuple_string, nodelist)

links = list(result)
print(links)
```

And now I am first trying to add the weight of 200 to every edge, before I want to read only the weight and than add it in a dictonary with the links. So my goal is to get a dictonary that just includes the link and the fitting weight like: dic = {'g1_ni1': 200, ...} Problem is that there is always these type problems and so it is not working to get the weight lonely.

```
#weights/lenghts
for source, target in G.edges():
    G[source][target][0]['weight'] = 200

for index, e in G.edges():
    print("weight %f\n" % int(e['weight']))

new = {links[1]: ...}
print(new)
```

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\DICPModell\graph.py", line 175, in <module>
    print("weight %f\n" % int(e['weight']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Please add any error messages or debugging to show the issue.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - `print(e)` . It seems `e` is normal `string` but you expect it is some `dictionary` .

Comment: in one line you use `G[source][target][0]['weight']` so maybe in this line you should do the same `G[source][e][0]['weight']` instead of `e['weight']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows problem in `print("weight %f\n" % int(e['weight']))` - so your problem is not to create dictionary but to get `weight` from edges.

---

You set `weight` using

```
for source, target in G.edges():
    G[source][target][0]['weight'] = 200
```

and the same way you should get and display `weight`

```
for source, target in G.edges():
    print("weight %f\n" % G[source][target][0]['weight'])
```

and this is your problem.

---

You could also use `f-string` to display `weight` and to create item in dictionary `new` (and you don't need `links` for this)

```
new = {}

for source, target in G.edges():
    print(f"{source:3} | {target:3} | weight: {G[source][target][0]['weight']}")
    new[f"{source}_{target}"] = G[source][target][0]['weight']

print(new)
```

---

Minimal working code with other changes:

```
import networkx as nx

# PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables
gates = 2
depots = 1 
zwischenknoten = 5 
parkpositionen = 2 

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

for x in range(1, gates+1):
    G.add_node(f'g{x}', pos=(x, 30), color='turquoise', type='gates')
    
for x in range(1, depots+1):
    G.add_node(f'bd{x}', pos=(x+gates, 30), color='green', type='depots')
    
for x in range(1, zwischenknoten+1):
    G.add_node(f'ni{x}', pos=(x, 20), color='blue')
    
for x in range(1, parkpositionen+1):
    G.add_node(f'p{x}', pos=(x+gates+depots, 10), color='red', type='parking')

for x in range(1, gates+1):
    G.add_edge(f'ni{x}', f'g{x}')
    G.add_edge(f'g{x}', f'ni{x}')
    
for x in range(1, depots+1):
    G.add_edge(f'ni{x+gates}', f'bd{x}')
    G.add_edge(f'bd{x}', f'ni{x+gates}')
    
for x in range(1, parkpositionen+1):
    G.add_edge(f'ni{x+gates+depots}', f'p{x}')
    G.add_edge(f'p{x}', f'ni{x+gates+depots}')
    
for x in range(1, zwischenknoten):
    G.add_edge(f'ni{x}', f'ni{x+1}')
    G.add_edge(f'ni{x+1}', f'ni{x}')

nodelist = G.edges()

links = list(map('_'.join, nodelist))
print(links)

for source, target in G.edges():
    G[source][target][0]['weight'] = 200

# --- before `for`-loop ---

new = {}

# --- `for`-loop ---

for source, target in G.edges():
    print(f"{source:>3} | {target:>3} | weight: {G[source][target][0]['weight']}")
    new[f"{source}_{target}"] = G[source][target][0]['weight']
    
# --- after `for`-loop ---

print(new)
```

Result:

```
['g1_ni1', 'g2_ni2', 'bd1_ni3', 'ni1_g1', 'ni1_ni2', 'ni2_g2', 'ni2_ni1', 'ni2_ni3', 'ni3_bd1', 'ni3_ni2', 'ni3_ni4', 'ni4_p1', 'ni4_ni3', 'ni4_ni5', 'ni5_p2', 'ni5_ni4', 'p1_ni4', 'p2_ni5']

 g1 | ni1 | weight: 200
 g2 | ni2 | weight: 200
bd1 | ni3 | weight: 200
ni1 |  g1 | weight: 200
ni1 | ni2 | weight: 200
ni2 |  g2 | weight: 200
ni2 | ni1 | weight: 200
ni2 | ni3 | weight: 200
ni3 | bd1 | weight: 200
ni3 | ni2 | weight: 200
ni3 | ni4 | weight: 200
ni4 |  p1 | weight: 200
ni4 | ni3 | weight: 200
ni4 | ni5 | weight: 200
ni5 |  p2 | weight: 200
ni5 | ni4 | weight: 200
 p1 | ni4 | weight: 200
 p2 | ni5 | weight: 200

{'g1_ni1': 200, 'g2_ni2': 200, 'bd1_ni3': 200, 'ni1_g1': 200, 'ni1_ni2': 200, 'ni2_g2': 200, 'ni2_ni1': 200, 'ni2_ni3': 200, 'ni3_bd1': 200, 'ni3_ni2': 200, 'ni3_ni4': 200, 'ni4_p1': 200, 'ni4_ni3': 200, 'ni4_ni5': 200, 'ni5_p2': 200, 'ni5_ni4': 200, 'p1_ni4': 200, 'p2_ni5': 200}
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)